# TempBuffer allocation with no references

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks

I'm optimizing the memory of the project I'm working on, in particular in the render texture zone.

In the cleaning process, I have found a render texture always allocated in memory with no references.

Because I couldn't find who creates it, I started to trim all garbage and all scripts that create a render texture at runtime, which means I nullified ALL constructors and ALL GetTemporary() methods of the RenderTexture class.
Now no one creates a render texture neither via script nor in the scene, but for some reason, the render texture is still there! (In editor AND in standalone build).

Is there a way to find out WHO creates something? To find out who is the culprit?

Thanks.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Memory profiler]

[image: Get temporary]

Comment: Well do you have any instances of `RenderTexture` in your assets maybe (search for `t:RenderTexture` in the Assets / ProjectView)? They can be created via the context menu and already lie around there -> no constructor nor GetTemporary will be called for these

Comment: And another thing: apparently [Anti-aliasing](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/PostProcessing-Antialiasing.html) also allocated Render texture(s) see e.g. [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/large-chunk-of-memory-used-by-a-single-tempbuffer-rendertexture.697100/)

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try and see if I can find something. Thanks!

Comment: After hours of trial and error, I finally found why the render texture is always allocated in memory. If **just one** camera in the scene uses [HDR](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HDR.html) Unity will always allocate memory for a render texture. To solve it, just disable it in the inspector. Thanks, @derHugo to point the direction to follow, please answer the question and I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trial and error, I finally found why the render texture is always allocated in memory. If **just one camera** in the scene uses [HDR](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HDR.html) Unity will always allocate memory for a render texture. To solve it, just disable it in the inspector. Thanks, @derHugo to point the direction to follow.